# My verification of the Darling-Erdös theorem does not work (?)

Tags: r, probability, convergence, cumulative-distribution-function

I am looking at the following limit theorem from the paper

*D. A. Darling, P. Erdös, A limit theorem for the maximum of normalized sums of independent random variables, Duke Math. J. 23(1): 143-155 (March 1956)*

[image]

I use R to check the result in the case where each $X_i$ is a standard normal. I use the following simple code to plot the right hand side on top of the left hand side when $n=100$:

```r
DE <- function(n, N){ # function that samples N times the U_n 
                      # statistic when each X_i is a N(0,1)
  for(i in 1:N){
  X.v <- rnorm(n=n, mean=0, sd=1)
  Sn <- cumsum(X.v)
  Un <- max(Sn/sqrt(1:n))
  write.table(Un, file=paste("sample_n=", n, "_N=", N, ".txt", 
    sep=""), append=TRUE, col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
  }
}

#plot the theoretical CDF:

x <- seq(from=-5, to=5, by=0.5)

plot(x=x, y=exp(-exp(-x)/(2*sqrt(pi))), type="l")

## Let us look at the asymptotic behavior of the distribution 
## of U_n as n grows and compare it to the limit predicted by 
## the Daring-Erdös theorem.
#n=100:
n=100
N=1e4
DE(n, N)

sample <- read.table(file=paste("sample_n=", n, "_N=", N, ".txt", 
                     sep=""))[, 1]

CDF <- c()
a <- sqrt(2*log(log(n)))
for(t in x){
  CDF <- c(CDF, mean(sample < (a + log(log(log(n)))/(2*a) + t/a)))
}

lines(x=x, y=CDF, type="l", col="orange")
legend("bottomright", legend=c(as.expression(bquote(bold("n=infty?"))), 
    as.expression(bquote(bold("n=1e2")))), col=c("black", "orange"), 
    lty=c(1,1), cex=1.2, lwd=4)
```

When I do this for increasing values of $n$ I observe that the left-hand side limit in the Darling-Erdös theorem appear to converges to something other than the predicted right-hand side:

[image]

Side note: In the paper

*J. Fan, S.-K. Lin, Test of Significance When Data Are Curves, Journal of the American Statistical Association, Vol. 93, No. 443 (Sep., 1998), pp.1007-1021*

they also check the Darling-Erdös theorem in the case where the $X_i$ are (standardized) chi-squares. They observe a similar discrepancy (see Table 1) which they attribute to "slow convergence". But they apparently only went up to $n=200$.

So on the one hand I have some disarmingly simple code which appears to contradict the Darling-Erdös theorem. Furthermore, this observation is backed by the above paper of Fan & Lin. On the other hand, the Darling-Erdös paper has been cited 271 times according to Google Scholar so it seems unlikely that it is wrong and nobody noticed it in 65 years.

What is going on ?!

Comment: While I have not seen the paper to comment specifically, you must not take in face value the number of citations. Yes, it can be indicative of the quality of the paper but that doesn't mean the paper couldn't be expanded or modified in later research.

Comment: @User1865345 Good point. From what I've seen, Darling and Erdös' Theorem 1 has been the subject of ongoing research: relaxation of the conditions, generalizations of and variations on the result, etc. I've seen no mention of an error in the original paper though.

Comment: The convergence is slow in most cases. Try exponential(1)